# Null check operator error when all variables have values?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Table_Calendar that I am trying to add events to. For some reason, a null check error is thrown (all variables have values) and no data is added to my Map.

I added the line // ### THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS to show where the error pops (inside the _loadMeetupsForMonth function).

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bark/helpers.dart' as helpers;
import 'package:loading_overlay/loading_overlay.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:line_icons/line_icons.dart';
import 'package:bark/addMeetup.dart';

class Meetups extends StatefulWidget {
  Meetups({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MeetupsState createState() => _MeetupsState();
}

class _MeetupsState extends State<Meetups> {
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Map<DateTime, List<CalendarEvent>> eventsForMonth =
      new Map<DateTime, List<CalendarEvent>>();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  List<Widget> _meetups = [];

// ### ADD NEW MEETUP
  _addMeetup() async {
    var _user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (_user != null) {
      var doRefresh = await Navigator.of(context)
          .push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddMeetup()));
      if (doRefresh == true || doRefresh == null) {
        // Refresh calendar
      }
    } else {
      // Not logged in. Show login popup.
      helpers.showLoginCreateForm(context);
    }
  }

  _loadMeetupsForMonth(DateTime _date) async {
    DateTime _start = DateTime(_date.year, _date.month, 1);
    DateTime _end = DateTime(_date.month < 12 ? _date.year : _date.year + 1,
        _date.month < 12 ? _date.month + 1 : 1, 0);

    print(_start);
    print(_end);
    print("Loading data START");

    // Get all for month
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _firestore
        .collection('Meetups')
        .where("is_deleted", isEqualTo: false)
        .where("meetup_time", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _start)
        .where("meetup_time", isLessThanOrEqualTo: _end)
        .orderBy("meetup_time", descending: true)
        .get();

    if (querySnapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
      print("No meetups for the month");
    } else {
      for (final doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        Timestamp _meetupTime = doc['meetup_time'] ?? DateTime.now();

        CalendarEvent _event = new CalendarEvent(
            title: doc["meetup_title"], postedBy: doc["poster_name"]);

        // ### THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS
        eventsForMonth[_meetupTime.toDate()]!.add(_event);
      }
    }

    print(
        "Loading data END: Event count = " + eventsForMonth.length.toString());
  }

  List<CalendarEvent> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    print("Getting for day " + day.toString());
    return eventsForMonth[day] ?? [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            LineIcons.chevronLeft,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                LineIcons.plus,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () => _addMeetup()),
        ],
        elevation: 1,
        title: Text(
          "Meetups",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        backgroundColor: helpers.appBarColor,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TableCalendar(
            onPageChanged: (focusedDay) => {_loadMeetupsForMonth(focusedDay)},
            firstDay: DateTime.now(),
            lastDay: DateTime.utc(2050, 12, 31),
            focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
            onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
              print(selectedDay);
            },
            eventLoader: (day) {
              return _getEventsForDay(day);
            },
          ), 
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    eventsForMonth = new Map<DateTime, List<CalendarEvent>>();
    _loadMeetupsForMonth(DateTime.now());
    super.initState();
  }
}

class CalendarEvent {
  final String title;
  final String postedBy;

  CalendarEvent({required this.title, required this.postedBy});
}
```

The error is:

```
Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: You assert that `eventsForMonth` has an existing entry for `_meetupTime.toDate()`, which is not true.  You probably want `(eventsForMonth[_meetupTime.toDate()] ??= []).add(...)`.

Comment: This worked as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

replacing `eventsForMonth[_meetupTime.toDate()]!.add(_event);` with

```
if(eventsForMonth[_meetupTime.toDate()]!=null) 
     eventsForMonth[_meetupTime.toDate()]!.add(_event);
else print("got null");
```

let me know if it solves